# 3 Tables Relations by Using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I have some relations on my db and I'm very confused how I can do this with eloquent. I have three tables that I want to connect eachother.

1. Users table - Contains users and these users have 3 roles (customers, managers, employee etc.) And users with manager role have more than one customers or employes.
2. Comps table - Contains company infos, (customers company, manager company, employee company etc.) employes can have same company.
3. Images table- this table contains user profile images, comp logo images etc.

I want to take a user's customers informations with images. I made the following relation between comp table and user table in User model. But I can't take comp image with this relation.

```
public function customers() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Comp', 'user_customers', 'user_id', 'comp_id');

}
```

user_customers table is a relation table which shows which user is a customer of which user.

user_customers table:

id,
user_id,
customer_user_id,
comp_id,

How can I get comp's logo image?

Comment: You can try with `hasManyThrough` or standard SQL JOIN.

Comment: I tried it but not suitable for my case. I make a relationship to customers table from user model with an intermeidary tabe. This is ok. But at the same time cutomer model has a relationship with images table. And I want to take user's customer with images by using user model.. but I can't to this.

Comment: So have you try to do this via standard SQL JOIN? You can create your custom method in your model with it (based on Eloquent joins or QueryBuilder)

Comment: I already did it with standart sql join.. I want to use laravel's eloquent orm. I got my answer from laravel discussion page. Thank you all. when getting model ı use with('customer.image', 'customer.image')... that works